# "Storing all the information and passing it to consumers" or "Store all the information and pass it to consumers"

Tags: sentence-construction

> 1. Storing all the information and passing it to consumers through the World Wide Web also entails costs.

What if I use *store* in place of *storing* and *pass* instead of *passing* there?

> 2. Store all the information and pass it to consumers through the World Wide Web also entails costs.

Comment: You could also use the infinitive  _to store_.

Comment: The comment from @BillJ seems to ignore the the "also entails costs" at the end of both statements. As far as I can see, that phrase makes 1 a complete sentence and disallows the imperative interpretation of 2.

Answer (score 1):

> **Storing** all the information and **passing** it to consumers through the World Wide Web also entails costs.

You can't substitute *store* and *pass* because they don't agree with the "entails costs" part of the sentence.

Instead, you can substitute **to store** and **to pass** (infinitive).

> To store all the information and to pass it to consumers through the World Wide Web also entails costs.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to change the end to make it correct:

"Store all the information and pass it to consumers through the World Wide Web, and X will entails costs".

What you're doing is turning it into a command, or "imperative". You're doing this by changing a sentence of "gerunds" to a sentence of "infinitives".

What this does is it turns an abstract idea into "X does Y to Z" or "X -> Z".

Doing this requires that you jump through grammatical hoops to make it work:

- Giving it all you got takes energy. -> Give it all you got. It will take energy, but it's worth it.
- The corparation is dedicated to investing 3% to the environment. -> The corporation dedicates itself to investing 3% to the environment.

(English is very flexible).